# Error #2136: swf contains invalid data

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

```
    public function starttank(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var Tankdrive:TankDrive = new TankDrive();
        Tankdrive.tankstart();
    }
```

It's saying that something in that function contains invalid data.

I have no idea what it is, i checked TankDrive and tankstart(); and both are correct, tankstart() is a public function...

I'm stumped...

EDIT: Error: 
Error #2136: The SWF file file:///C|/Users/BigRed/Desktop/TankDrive/TankDrive.swf contains invalid data.
    at mainmenu/starttank()

That's the error...

And above the starttank() function is still the same...

Comment: Also i found the error was on the line 'var Tankdrive:TankDrive = new TankDrive();'... changing both 'Tankdrive's to 'tankDrive' didn't fix it, i have no idea what the problem is because i have the exact same line in another class and it works fine... (but accesses a different class, I check and tankstart() is a class in TankDrive...)

Comment: You need to post the exact error and line number, so we can help you. What you provided is not enough to help you.

Comment: Are you using an external .swf or a .swc ?

Comment: I don't even know what a .swc is, but I don't know as I can't see the extensions... I put the exact code in the main post, sorry for the delay but I couldn't get on the fast computer to get to it for a while.

Comment: Would really have to see your source to figure out what's wrong. You might be getting an error there, but the reason might be related to your class or something else in your project. If you can make your project available, I will take a look at it.

Comment: http://www.filefactory.com/file/complete.php/62p3diclct2n/5ecyllfcjx8h/3abyryd06sjl/eyeusburjy5/qyvha8zfgyz/2e2mhmmbb0n/4q27hfpbpo4l/5kot80su7br7/343k400x3dy9/   They should all be their.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I looked over the files.

I'm puzzled by what you are trying to do.

Your Document class is TankDrive, and it creates an instance of mainmenu, which create ANOTHER instance of TankDrive when you click a button. Which is not what I think you want to do, or you think it's allowing you to access your document class. -- it's not. It's attempting to create a whole new instance of your game.

In short, your design is not making sense, and it's also causing a conflict with the document class resulting in that error.

The quick solution is to NOT have your EventListener & handler for the click in the mainmenu class, and then call the tankstart() method of your document class instead of attempting to create a new instance of TankDrive.

First move that listener into the document class and modify like this :

```
main.enterTank.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, starttank);
```

and then move your handler to the TankDrive class and modify as follows :

```
public function starttank(event:MouseEvent):void
{
         tankstart();
}
```

This is not the only way to do this, and not really the way that I would do it. But I think that discussion is beyond the scope of this question.

If you want you can contact me at prototype.in.training@gmail.com for more details on that.

Comment: I was trying to do what this tutorial told me to do: http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/2008/10/09/avoider-game-tutorial-3/ (Scroll about a third of the way down.)

Comment: Yes, this tutorial touches on the topic of dispatching events, to notify the document class of something. Which is one way to do what you were trying to do, but not what you were actually doing.

Comment: I was trying to pull all the buttons for the menu into the menu and all the players/enemies/mines into the play level with the level...

Comment: Mostly i'm wondering why what i had wouldn't work for this but worked fine in the lv1 class?

Comment: Because the class happened to be the document class. You tried to instantiate another instance of the document class. I wouldn't waste too much time wondering about something that is a bad idea to start.

Comment: You have that same line in there, BUT this error you are getting is not a compile error -- it's a runtime error. Execution of the code never got to the instantiation of the document class as it's inside a condition. You were getting a runtime error, so that line of code was never attempted to be executed.

Comment: If you don't believe me, just move that same line into the constructor of lvl1 class where it'll get executed when you create lev1 in the document class.  Or you can put it in your onstart() method of the document class and you'll get the same issue.

Comment: But let me reiterate, it's a bad idea to create another instance of your document class as you have done in two different classes. Will only lead to headaches. So... my advice again, is to focus on a different approach instead of wasting time on and wondering about something that WILL NOT work.

Comment: Well considering I copied the code from lv1 to here, i'm not sure what the difference would be... I need to know why it won't work...

Comment: I told you why it won't work. The only reason you aren't getting the error in lv1 is because it never reaches that code... If it did, it would give you the same error. It's a runtime error, NOT a compile time error.

Comment: As I said above - "You tried to instantiate another instance of the document class." -- you CANNOT do that. You could have that same line at all over in your code and it will compile just fine, but as soon as execution reaches ANY one of those lines, you will get a runtime error.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out what i should have did -- MovieClip(parent).class(); and I figured out why the other one showed no errors: errors only occur when i actually run teh code...

Comment: Yes, you can use that method, but utilizing the event system is really the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have an instance name that's also a class name (and the compiler has assumed that you meant to reference the latter). You probably meant to call your TankDrive variable 'tankDrive', so changing your code snippet to the following will probably help:

```
public function starttank(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var tankdrive:TankDrive = new TankDrive();
    tankdrive.tankstart();
}
```

It's common and recommended to start all public variable names with a lower case letter, private variables with an underscore, and class names with a capital, though this isn't enforced by the language itself, so this kind of thing can happen.

Here are some guides on conventional variable and function naming that can help you keep track of what each of your vars and functions are supposed to do:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/variables.html
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/functions.html

Good luck!

Comment: This changes nothing, and incase you didn't notice the variable was originally Tankdrive with a lower case d...

Comment: Look again; it's the first letter in particular that should be lowercase, and for the variable name only. The key is to ensure that your instance names are not the same as your class names (and they are identical in your post - `var TankDrive:TankDrive` will throw an error). If you have additional errors, post more of your code.

Comment: His post has var `Tankdrive:TankDrive` , which is valid. Not a good practice, but valid nonetheless.

Comment: And besides, it changes nothing: I tested it with both lowercase and it didn't work...